# Load Configurable Pricing Adjustments

Tags: product, database, price, import, configurable-product

I'm trying to import configurable products with the price corrections. The products and the relations are already in, but I can't seem to get the price corrections working. This is what the configurable look like with the price corrections. Does anyone have any ideas what's going wrong? Any advice is appreciated, thank you!

```
sku,price,_super_products_sku,_super_attribute_price_corr
product_1_11CONF,76,product_1_15,0
,,product_1_12,15
,,product_1_13,9
,,product_1_14,4
product_2_11CONF,63,product_2_11,36
,,product_2_15,0
,,product_2_12,12
,,product_2_13,7
,,product_2_14,3
```

**Update**
I updated the import to look more like this:

```
sku,price,_super_products_sku,_super_attribute_code,_super_attribute_option,_super_attribute_price_corr
product_1-11HOME,395,product_115,ac_license_level,100-249,0
,,product_1-14,,10-24,30
,,product_1-13,,25-49,57
,,product_1-11,,50-99,68
,,product_1-12,,1-9,94
```

But it is still not working. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the options also. Try it with the option and option's value also. (`_super_attribute_option` & `_super_attribute_code`). It should work.

If memory serves the Module removes pricing that does not have a option that is used.
And you are not using any options.

Comment: Hey, I tried what you said and I updated it to look like the abov. It's still not working though. Is there a special order or something that I need?

Comment: Ok, Order Should not matter. As long as the columns match up.
Maybe you need to try replace complex attributes.
I am not sure. I might be looking at it again.
If so I'll update.